# Choosing a data structure for polyvalent cuneiform signs

Tags: database, search, data-structures

I'm working on developing a search engine for cuneiform signs, which is complicated by several things:

- Each sign can have multiple syllabic meanings (polyphony)
- Each sign can have multiple logographic meanings (polyvalency)
- Each syllabic meaning can have multiple signs (homophony)
- Each sign has multiple variants
- Each sign can be part of other signs

Additionally, each sign will have several numbers (standard indices from the literature) associated with them.

What kind of data structure/database would be best for storing these entries? Ideally, I would like to be able to search by any of the fields and be able to return to the user an ordered list, sorted by similarity (I'm still working out the similarity functions). It doesn't necessarily need to be very efficient to edit the data after it is made, as this will primarily be a static resource. It would also be good, though less essential, if associated records were connected somehow: sign AB is part of signs ABCD and ABMN, and so is associated to them in some way.

An example of a sign:

The DA sign () has syllabic meanings:

- ta
- ta2
- qab3
- le10

and logographic meanings:

- le'u
- lu
- tehu
- etc

And composes part of signs FOO, BAR, etc. The sign has MZL number 561.